# Flow eror "Property is missing in exports". Why?

Tags: flowtype

I can't understand what Flow is complaining about. When I run flow on these two files, I get an error `Property MyType is missing in exports [1]`

File defining the types:

```
// types.js
// @flow

export type MyType = {
  from: string,
  to: string,
  subject: string,
  text: string,
};
```

File using the types:

```
// myfile.js
// @flow
const { MyType } = require('./types') // flow error on this line

const foo = ({
  from = 'default',
  to,
  subject,
  text,
}: MyType) => {
  doSOmething();
}
```

What is the right syntax to export my type? And where is it in the Flow documentation, it only seems to ever talk about exporting whole modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { MyType } = require('./types')
```

is real JavaScript, meaning that even when you remove Flowtype declarations, that would still run. `MyType` does not exist at runtime because all Flowtype logic is stripped out before execution.

You should import that as

```
import type { MyType } from "./types";
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that Flow uses import/export and not require, no matter what you're using elsewhere to import/require modules.

Comment: Yep, most people just end up using ES module import/export. If you're using Flow, you already have a build step so adding in the `babel-preset-env` is just 1 extra plugin to be able to use the `import/export` syntax.

Comment: @saadq The module transform is not necessary for `import type` to work. It is entirely separate from ES6 import syntax. The normal Flow-stripping logic will remove them just fine.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant that because you have to use the `import type` syntax, you might as well use the extra babel-plugin to use `import/export` for everything else as well rather than having a mix of `require` and `import`.

Comment: @saadq Gotcha, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned under [Module Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/), if you read it carefully you'll see it is talking about exporting both types and values and how to import each.  It's a bit misleading because the page title implies you are importing a 'module' - in fact you are importing the exported types or values.

The `type` keyword should be used on the `import` statement to indicate that you want to import the type, not the value.

Because you've exported a type, not a value, but attempted to import a value, you get the error.

```
import type { MyType } from './types'
```